# Finding the sum of select options times inputs fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the average for a given subjects and to print the average directly whenever the user change a value.

I am using an input fields to input the marks and a corresponding select options for the hours to each subject.
I can do it correctly for one subject but when I add the class 'subject' to other divs. I can't figure how to do the same thing without mixing the subject values.

Part of my HTML code :

```
<!-- Fourth Subject -->
      <div class="form-row text-center subject">
        <div class="col-4   ">
          <input type="text" name="mark4" class="form-control text-center mark" placeholder="العلامة">
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="State">
        </div>-->
        <select id="select" name="option4" class="custom-select col-4 text-center hours" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
          <option selected>عدد الساعات</option>
          <option value="1">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" name='subject4' class="form-control text-center" placeholder="إسم المادة">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Fourth Subject -->
      </br>
      <!-- Fifth Subject -->
      <div class="form-row text-center subject">
        <div class="col-4   ">
          <input type="text" name="mark5" class="form-control text-center mark" placeholder="العلامة">
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="State">
        </div>-->
        <select id="select" name="option5" class="custom-select col-4 text-center hours" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
          <option  selected>عدد الساعات</option>
          <option value="1">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <div class="col-4">
          <input type="text" name='subject5' class="form-control text-center" placeholder="إسم المادة">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Fifth Subject -->
```

And here is how I get the values for one subject using jQuery:

```
$('.subject').keyup(function () {

  var mark = 0;
  var hours = 0;
  $('.mark').change(function() {
    mark = Number($(this).val());
    console.log('mark is ' + mark);
    hours = $('select[name=option5]').val();
    $(".hours").change(function() {
      hours = $('select[name=option5]').val();
      console.log('hours are ' + hours);
    });
    $('#avg').val(mark*hours);
  });

  $(".hours").change(function() {
    hours = $('select[name=option5]').val();
    console.log('hours are ' + hours);

    $('.mark').each(function() {
      mark = Number($(this).val());
      console.log('mark is ' + mark);
      $('#avg').val(mark*hours);
    });
  });
});
```

the avg should be (mark1 * hours_for_mark1 + mark2 * hours_for_mark_2) / number_of_hours.
Is there any way to do it using jQuery ? or even a better structure !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have serious problems when adding event handlers on dom elements. For example you should not add new events inside `keyup` because it causes to be added another event listener every time you press a key and duplicate executions will be happen. Try this below it is quite self explanatory:

```
var handler = function() {
  var total = 0;
  var totalHours = 0;
  $('.subject').each(function(){
    var mark = Number($(this).find('.mark').val())
    var hours = Number($(this).find('.hours').val())
    total += mark * hours;
    totalHours += hours;
  })

  $('#avg').text(total/totalHours);

}
$('.subject .mark').keyup(handler)
$('.subject .hours').change(handler)
```

Also you can check the solution in jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/timugivobi/edit?html,js,output
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot Yavuz Tas. I had to set hours = 0 if the value was NaN. To calculate the value even if the number of the subjects entered by the user is less than all subjects and that's all. Thank you again.